# How to update merged array after one is being updated in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, concatenation

In the following example, how can I make `mix` to update to reflect changes made to any of the merged arrays?

```
var fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Bannana"]
var cars =  ["Cobalt", "Durango", "Jetta"]

var mix = fruits + cars

print(fruits)
print(cars)

print(mix)

cars.append("Mustang") // cars array modification

print(mix) // how to update mix to show Mustang?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computed variable is what are you looking for, I believe:

```
var fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Bannana"]
var cars =  ["Cobalt", "Durango", "Jetta"]

var mix: [String] {return fruits + cars}

print(mix)
//["Apple", "Orange", "Bannana", "Cobalt", "Durango", "Jetta"]

cars.append("Mustang") // cars array modification
print(mix)
//["Apple", "Orange", "Bannana", "Cobalt", "Durango", "Jetta", "Mustang"]
```

Comment: Good answer.  I didn't know stand-alone properties were even possible.

Comment: He beat me to it... I was busy making a swift sandbox example: https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57c977168836ca0c17d17b90

Comment: Ah, computer properties, very cool. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that every time mix is accessed then the two arrays will be merged again.  This is fine for small arrays (such as tin the question) but  for large arrays then it may be better to only recalculate mix when one or other of the source arrays are updated.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the simplest way (perhaps not the most efficient)...

```
var fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Bannana"]
var cars =  ["Cobalt", "Durango", "Jetta"]

var mix = fruits + cars

print(fruits)
print(cars)

print(mix)

cars.append("Mustang") // cars array modification

mix = fruits + cars
print(mix) // Now shows Mustang.
```

`mix` does not contain a reference back to `cars` so you can't expect it to be dynamically updated when `cars` is updated.